# move linux directory unless it already exists

Tags: linux, terminal, file-move

I need a way to move a linux directory and all of it's contents only if it doesn't currently exist in the target location. If it does currently exist (including all sub-folders and files) then the source folder can just can just be removed recursively.

I currently use the following framework but wish to expand it to meet the above criteria.

```
mv /source/* /target
```

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`rsync -av --remove-source-files source/ destination/ && rm -rf source/`

Replace `source/` and `destination/` accordingly.

[Source](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/81092)

Comment: Great. Just what I needed.

Answer (score 0):

Gnu `mv` has the `-n` or `--no-clobber` option. Unfortunately, it seems to return with an successful exit status even if the `mv` was a no-op due to the `--no-clobber` option, however it seems that in your use case, you can simply do the `--no-clobber` move and then clear the source if the move succeeds regardless of whether or not it did anything.